# Regex devuelve todos los caracteres en lugar de los que se repiten dos veces o más

Tags: javascript, regex

¿Por qué el siguiente código no me devuelve solo los caracteres que se repiten dos veces o más? Me los devuelve todos aunque no se repitan

```
var str = "aaBbqwerty119";
var sol = str.match(/\w{2,}/gi);
document.write(sol);//aaBbqwerty119
```

No entiendo por qué me devuelve `aaBbqwerty119` y no `aaBb11`.

Answer (score 4):

Te da un resultado lógico, esa expresión busca **cualquier** letra que aparezca dos o más veces, no que se repita: que aparezca.
Necesitas referencias inversas dentro de la expresión regular. Un patrón que busca una letra seguida de ella misma una o más veces. Esto lo consigues con \n, donde n es el número de orden de un subpatrón.
En este caso

```js
var str = "aaBbqwerty119";
console.log(str.match(/(\w)\1{1,}/gi));
```

Verás que obtienes "aa","Bb", "11". Si pones

```js
const str = "aabbqwerrrry11999";
console.log(str.match(/(\w)\1{1,}/gi));
```

El resultado es "aa", "bb", "rrrr", "11", "999"

Los patrones con referencias a la propia búsqueda son bastante potentes, pero a veces difíciles de entender.

Answer (score 1):

`(\w)\1+` matcheará todos los caracteres que estén repetidos **consecutivamente** 2 o mas veces. Si los caracteres repetidos pueden no ser consecutivos, se pueden ordenar antes de la regex. Ver el caso de la "z".

```js
const str = "zaaBbqwzerty119z";

const res = [...str].sort().join('').match(/(\w)\1+/g);

console.log(res);
```